# mpv subtitle font

Tags: mpv

I have looked in `mpv.conf` and in `input.conf` and don't see any setting for subtitle font. I see size but not font name.

However I see that it must be a configurable value because I have mpv running on two different machines and see they are different from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see different fonts is that video files can provide their own fonts, but it is also possible to set your own font.   It is documented here: https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-sub-font

```
--sub-font=<name>
Specify font to use for subtitles that do not themselves specify a particular font. The default is sans-serif.

Examples

--sub-font='Bitstream Vera Sans'
--sub-font='Comic Sans MS'
Note
```